# Auto decorator on all Get requests in Google App Engine - Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to log (send metrics to statsD ) every GET/POST request in GAE.

So thats my decorator :

```
def log_request():
    def actual_decorator(method):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            // send metrics that have the request name as the name space
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return actual_decorator
```

Of course i don't want to go over all my GET requests and put a @log_request() out there. Is there a way to catch them all on a global level ?

(not using Django)

Comment: If you are using a `BaseHandler()` then it should apply it there..

Comment: Also you have to be more specific on what you are using.. is it `webapp2`?

Comment: Yes we are using webapp2

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it's possible (in Python) to inherit a decorated method automatically to all subclasses. You must explicitly declare decorators for each method.

If all you are looking for is analytics, you can use the logging service and a ScheduledTask to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar thing recently, you can wrap the WSGIApplication in a middleware that log the request. I do not know about statsD, in my case I log the request to datastore.